# How to create Self signed certificates

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to open my homepage with HTTPS in my test server. Is there a way i can create Self signed certifcates and see if  https works. Please suggest me some links or any ideas with how to do!!

Its an ASP.Net project and IIS V6.0

I appreciate all your help :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`makecert.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3.aspx) tool to create a self-signed certificate. The following command line should do:

```
makecert -r -pe -n CN="www.example.com" -b 05/10/2010 -e 12/22/2011 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localmachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12
```

For further details and examples see the documentation of [makecert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3.aspx).

Comment: +1 This is an excellent way too, and probably easier to get the SDK than the IIS6 Resource Kit... but especially since it looks like 0xA3 has included examples of all the relevant parameters you should be using.

Comment: I first run this "makecert outputCertificateFile" in the SDK Command Prompt. It shows succeeded. Then i ran the command the way it is given just changing www.example.com to mywebsite.com, it throws an error "Too many parameters"

Comment: I am new and learning. If you could spare some more time, it would be great! Thank you. I have SSL on my production web server, so it works fine but for the test server, i need self signed certificate.

Comment: @Ram, I fixed the command.  It should work as soon as my edit is approved.  The problem is that the command was copied verbatim from MSDN, and the example there is using invalid hyphen characters (0x96) on every switch except -sky. It's not visually obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the IIS6 Resource Kit, you can use a tool therein to create one. More info:

[Creating Self-Signed SSL Certificates on IIS6 and Windows 2003](http://codeforeternity.com/blogs/technology/archive/2008/02/15/creating-self-signed-ssl-certificates-on-iis-6-0-and-windows-server-2003.aspx)

[IIS6 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/993a8a36-5761-448f-889e-9ae58d072c09.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [makecert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28VS.80%29.aspx) util